# Extreme distortion/clipping plugin

Tags: distortion, clipping, plug-in

I'm looking for a plugin that can model more extreme distortion effects such as the gain clipping you would hear when an unprotected mic gets hit by a gust of wind, or craps out from someone screaming into it.  I'm talking something that will really mangle the audio in a unique way.  Does any such thing exist?

Answer (score 2):

[Ohmicide](https://www.ohmforce.com/ViewProduct.do?p=Ohmicide) from Ohm Force is specifically made to provide over-the-top distortion effects. Available as 32/64-bit Audio Unit, VST, and RTAS.

Comment: I second Ohmicide. It can be a bit unwieldy but it certainly does destroy sound! It's hit or miss but sometimes the results are gold. Oh, and thanks for posting an actual "sound design" questions!

Answer (score 0):

Fabfilter saturn does a lot of nasty distortion like the rectify or destroy programs. And it's also a multiband proccesor giving you lots of nice costumization effects

It's avaiable as 64 and 32 bit VST. I don't know about mac but i think it's AU.

It alsohase a mono version that comes with it when you buy it as well as sidechain capable versions for both mono and normal(stereo) versions

Answer (score 0):

[Bad Buss Mojo](http://www.stillwellaudio.com/plugins/bad-buss-mojo/) is an option too! It's actually a clipper. Go full mix and non-linear and play with the controls.